# Overriding automatic projection definitions for layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is there a way to set an override for a specific projection in QGIS?

I want layers that have a specific projection to be set with a custom projection I've defined.

I can define it manually, but wondering if there's a way to do it automatically for all current and new layers in the project.

Comment: Please, could you edit your question by adding an example of what should you do _manually_?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is in QGIS 2.18

```
Settings > Options > CRS
```

Under **CRS for new Layers** Select the ones you require.

[image]